# Is finding the percolation threshold of an arbitrary continuum system P or NP complex?

Tags: probability, computational-complexity, percolation, geometric-complexity

By arbitrary I mean an infinite 2D system of e.g. 3 different sizes of rectangle like in figure 5 of https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.88.012101

Answer (score 0):

Introduire la question de percolation Z^2: est-ce qu'il peut y avoir (avec probabilite>0) des chemins ouvert partant de 0 allant arbitrairement loin?

Comment: Please write in English.